# Filter telemetry data on dashboard from input entered in custom widget textbox - Thingsboard

Tags: search, filter, widget, thingsboard

I have created a custom widget with open textbox and search button in Thingsboard IoT open-source platform. On click of button i want to filter the telemetry rows listed in thermometers widget.
e.g. In attached image, if i enter Thermometer-1A in red highlighted textbox then on click of search button Entity Name highlighted in blue color should be filtered with the input value in Thermometers widget.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[Thingboard Dashboard custom widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc0uB.png)

Comment: Hey do you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Intercommunication is only possible between custom widgets. Our standard widgets do not provide an API for communication.

1. If you only want to filter data in the table widget, the easiest way is to use 'search' button in the top right corner of the table widget.
2. If the first option does not work for you, you should implement your custom table widget and add an API for intercommunication. For example, Search widget will broadcast some event when a button is pressed. And custom table widget will listen to messages of a specific type and acts accordingly.

Here is a link that describes to messaging works inside AngularJS
https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Comment: Can you share some example of that?